# Adbmob House ad creation section blank

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, admob

1. Basically I use admob to show in house banner and interstitial ads for my new project. I have tried in the past few weeks. However, suddenly the admob house ad section seems corrupted. When we go to banner/ interstitial ad creation section, a blank page appear and we cant choose type or create any ad.
   Please see the attached screenshot. Anyone has the same issue???
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PfLD.png
2. Right now interstitial ads only show once per ad per device so if I have 2 house ad, the interstitial ad only show for the first 2 times app launch. the third time, admob reply with error: no ad to be shown in the inventory.

Any one has a solution for this? We want to show latest promotion in house ad to user everytime they open the app and this can be change to new promotion easily on our website. so in the end, we most likely only has 1 ad in the inventory...

If you have any solution, it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point: Refresh your cache of your browser or use another browser